# Elastic Search cursor id not found

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting following error while adding/updating data into elasticsearch : cursor id 51077216784572 not found.
What it means? What is the root cause of the issue?

Comment: Try to provide more details. How your data looks like, which commands do you run and what is exact message when executing a command.

Comment: I am updating elasticsearch document. can ypu please tell when that error comes in elasticsearch?

Comment: As i said before please provide more information.